# How to clone peoject with git using putty.ppk in mac?

Tags: git, osx-snow-leopard, clone, putty

I am new to both MAC OS and GIT, I have to clone a project using GIT under MAC OS 10.6.8.

All that I have done are as follow:

1. Download and install GIT

   ```
   $ git --version
   git version 1.7.5.4
   ```
2. Download and install PuTTY

all that I have are

1. test.ppk
2. test_putty.ppk
3. ssh://git@:/~/folder1/subfolder1/test.git

Comment: Why would you want to install PuTTY on an OSX machine?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know specifically which tools are provided under OSX with PuTTY but you need to do one of two things

- Export the public & private keys from the PPK to ~/.ssh/id_rsa / and ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub as OpenSSH keys. On Windows you can do this with PuTTYGen by loading they PPK file and it will display the corresponding information for OpenSSH.  This way you can use the native ssh client.
- If there is an OSX analog of Windows "plink", see if you can set the environment variable GIT_SSH to point to this executable.

I hope this helps some. I think I might be confusing the issue though.

If you are looking to use exclusively OpenSSH style access, then you need to read the public & private keys out of the PPK file (assuming Windows PuTTYGen).

Answer (score 1):

Just enquiring but why would you need to use putty, is this a work mandate or something? I thought OSX came with its own openssh client?

normaly it should just be

```
git clone ssh://git@:/~/folder1/subfolder1/test.git
```

Does this not work on your install? I presume this is a pseudo URI you gave since normally you'd need to specify a host to clone via ssh from, like git@somehost.com/folder/blah.git
(if possible/allowed could you post the complete git location/command you use?)

if you get any authentication errors make sure that your identity file (~/.ssh/authorized_keys) is set to appropriate permissions and has been filled with the correct keys for the remote location.